# Create single row dataframe from list of list PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data like this `data = [[1.1, 1.2], [1.3, 1.4], [1.5, 1.6]]` I want to create a PySpark dataframe

I already use

```
dataframe = SQLContext.createDataFrame(data, ['features'])
```

but I always get

```
+--------+---+
|features| _2|
+--------+---+
|     1.1|1.2|
|     1.3|1.4|
|     1.5|1.6|
+--------+---+
```

how can I get result like below?

```
+----------+
|features  |
+----------+
|[1.1, 1.2]|
|[1.3, 1.4]|
|[1.5, 1.6]|
+----------+
```

Comment: You can create a schema and provide while creating a dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it's useful to think of the argument to `createDataFrame()` as a list of tuples where each entry in the list corresponds to a row in the DataFrame and each element of the tuple corresponds to a column.

You can get your desired output by making each element in the list a tuple:

```
data = [([1.1, 1.2],), ([1.3, 1.4],), ([1.5, 1.6],)]
dataframe = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ['features'])
dataframe.show()
#+----------+
#|  features|
#+----------+
#|[1.1, 1.2]|
#|[1.3, 1.4]|
#|[1.5, 1.6]|
#+----------+
```

Or if changing the source is cumbersome, you can equivalently do:

```
data = [[1.1, 1.2], [1.3, 1.4], [1.5, 1.6]]
dataframe = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(map(lambda x: (x, ), data), ['features'])
dataframe.show()
#+----------+
#|  features|
#+----------+
#|[1.1, 1.2]|
#|[1.3, 1.4]|
#|[1.5, 1.6]|
#+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `map` function to convert the `tuples` to `array` and use it in `createDataFrame`

```
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data).map(lambda x: [x]), ['features'])
```

You should get as you desire

```
+----------+
|  features|
+----------+
|[1.1, 1.2]|
|[1.3, 1.4]|
|[1.5, 1.6]|
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Vector Assembler function, from your code I guess you are doing this to train a machine learning model, and vector assembler works the best for that case. You can also add the  assembler in the pipeline.

```
assemble_feature=VectorAssembler(inputCol=data.columns,outputCol='features')
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[assemble_feature])
pipeline.fit(data).transform(data)
```