# How to create an dataframe from a dictionary where each item is a column in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to make a new dataframe from a dictionary. The dictionary contains column names as keys and lists of columnar data as values. For example:

```
col_dict = {'col1': [1, 2, 3],
            'col2': [4, 5, 6]}
```

I need this as a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|     1|     4|
|     2|     5|
|     3|     6|
+------+------+
```

It doesn't seem like there's an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a pandas DataFrame and convert to a Spark DataFrame:

#### With Pandas

```python
col_dict = {'col1': [1, 2, 3],
            'col2': [4, 5, 6]}

import pandas as pd
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(col_dict)
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
df.show()
#+----+----+
#|col1|col2|
#+----+----+
#|   1|   4|
#|   2|   5|
#|   3|   6|
#+----+----+
```

#### Without Pandas

If pandas is not available, you'll just have to manipulate your data into a form that works for the `createDataFrame()` function. Quoting myself from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750921/5858851):

> I find it's useful to think of the argument to createDataFrame() as a
>   list of tuples where each entry in the list corresponds to a row in
>   the DataFrame and each element of the tuple corresponds to a column.

```python
colnames, data = zip(*col_dict.items())
print(colnames)
#('col2', 'col1')
print(data)
#([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])
```

Now we need to modify data so that it's a list of tuples, where each element contains the data for the corresponding column. Luckily, this is easy using `zip`:

```python
data = zip(*data)
print(data)
#[(4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3)]
```

Now call `createDataFrame()`:

```python
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, colnames)
df.show()
#+----+----+
#|col2|col1|
#+----+----+
#|   4|   1|
#|   5|   2|
#|   6|   3|
#+----+----+
```

Comment: I don't have pandas available, unfortunately :/

Comment: This works. I'll wait a bit before accepting. This was the route I was exploring, but I'm worried about how this could perform on very large datasets