# How to make a spark dataframe from multiple lists in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark and have multiple lists like this:

```
A = [5, 2, 3, 24, 1, ....]
B = ["Jim", "Bob", "Tyler", ....]
C = [5, 6,5, 5, 5, ....]
```

I want the data frame to have 3 columns, (each list as one column). How can I do this with pyspark?

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796486/how-to-create-an-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-each-item-is-a-column-in-pysp/48796663#48796663) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The link @James Flanagin produced is probably best, however this method was not in that answer, and is useful in certain scenario's.

This is my preferred way of creating pyspark dataframes. It's especially useful when unit testing specific data.

Note the usage of nested `Row` objects.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

df =spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
            Row(user_jid='ryan_123',
                timestamp="2018-08-01T00:00:00.111Z",
                common_data=Row(platform='android')),
        ]).toDF()
```