# Calculate Mode of each Column of dataframe, Store it in a list and make a dataframe using the it

Tags: pyspark

I am  finding the 'MODE' of all columns in my dataframe and storing them in a list.
The code that is calculating my MODE of each column :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
 #calculating mode value
mode_val = []
for i in df_num.columns :
       cnts = df_num.groupBy(i).count()
       mode = cnts.join(
       cnts.agg(max("count").alias("max_")), col("count") == col("max_")
        ).limit(1)
        mode2 = mode.withColumn(i,col(i).cast("double"))
        mode_val.append(mode2.first()[0])
```

## output

[6500.0,
 0.0,
 None,
 1300.0,
 3.0,
 3.0,
 0.0,
 None,
 38000.0]

When i am trying to convert the list into a dataframe i seem to get an error.

This is my code for converting my list of MODE to dataframe :

```
univar_df4 = spark.createDataFrame(mode_val,["Mode"])
```

## error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-d5ca3ecf8d79> in <module>()
      1 #not able to apply to dataframe.
----> 2 univar_df4 = spark.createDataFrame(mode_val,["Mode"])

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    535             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    536         else:
--> 537             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    538         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    539         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    399 
    400         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 401             struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data)
    402             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    403             data = map(converter, data)

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in _inferSchemaFromList(self, data)
    331             warnings.warn("inferring schema from dict is deprecated,"
    332                           "please use pyspark.sql.Row instead")
--> 333         schema = reduce(_merge_type, map(_infer_schema, data))
    334         if _has_nulltype(schema):
    335             raise ValueError("Some of types cannot be determined after inferring")

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _infer_schema(row)
    990 
    991     else:
--> 992         raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
    993 
    994     fields = [StructField(k, _infer_type(v), True) for k, v in items]

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain that error, I will [quote myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750921/5858851) from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745029/create-single-row-dataframe-from-list-of-list-pyspark/):

> I find it's useful to think of the argument to `createDataFrame()` as a
>   list of tuples where each entry in the list corresponds to a row in
>   the DataFrame and each element of the tuple corresponds to a column.

You can get your desired output by making each element in the list a tuple:

```python
mode_val = [6500.0, 0.0, None, 1300.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, None, 38000.0]
mode_val = [(x,) for x in mode_val]
print(mode_val)
#[(6500.0,), (0.0,), (None,), (1300.0,), (3.0,), (3.0,), (0.0,), (None,), (38000.0,)]
```

Now create the DataFrame:

```python
univar_df4 = spark.createDataFrame(mode_val,["Mode"])
univar_df4.show()
#+-------+
#|   Mode|
#+-------+
#| 6500.0|
#|    0.0|
#|   null|
#| 1300.0|
#|    3.0|
#|    3.0|
#|    0.0|
#|   null|
#|38000.0|
#+-------+
```

However, it seems as though your goal is to get the mode for each column into a new DataFrame. Here is an alternative way that doesn't rely on storing the values in a list:

Create an example DataFrame:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

data = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 3, 3),
    (2, 3, 2)
]

df_num = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["a", "b", "c"])
df_num.show()
#+---+---+---+
#|  a|  b|  c|
#+---+---+---+
#|  1|  2|  3|
#|  1|  3|  3|
#|  2|  3|  2|
#+---+---+---+
```

Use list comprehension + `reduce` with `union` to get the mode for each column:

```python
mode = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.union(b),
    [
        df_num.groupBy(i)\
            .count()\
             .sort(f.col("count").desc())\
             .limit(1)\
             .select(
                f.lit(i).alias("col"),
                f.col(i).alias("mode")
            ) 
        for i in df_num.columns
    ]
)
mode.show()
#+---+----+
#|col|mode|
#+---+----+
#|  a|   1|
#|  b|   3|
#|  c|   3|
#+---+----+
```

Inside the list comprehension, we are iterating over all the columns in the DataFrame and doing a `groupBy()` and `count()` (as you were doing). But, instead of looking for the row where the count was equal to the max, I sorted the column descending and used `limit(1)` to get the max value.

After this step, the DataFrame will have two columns and one row. We manipulate the values to transform this into a DataFrame of two columns: `(column_name, mode)`.

Finally, we reduce the list by calling union to concatenate all of the rows together.