# Creating a python spark dataframe from pyodbc rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do something simple here. Get rows from pyodbc and use this as an input for creating a dataframe

```
import pyodbc
import sys
import csv

connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MySQL")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

rows = cursor.fetchall()
column_names = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]

print(rows)
print(column_names)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows,column_names)
```

But I'm getting the following trace:

```
raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'pyodbc.Row'>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try `createDataFrame((tuple(r) for r in rows), column_names)`. A `pyodbc.Row` is just a glorified tuple anyway.

Comment: Additionally to @user2722968 comment, please keep in mind that this just won't scale.

Comment: I'm getting "py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10595.fit.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column label must be of type NumericType but was actually of type StringType.
 at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)" when I use "spark.createDataFrame((tuple(r) for r in rows), column_names)" for ML input. This doesn't happen with: spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("temp.csv"). Any ideas?

Comment: @NEO I'm not sure why that's not working for you but try: `createDataFrame([(r,) for r in rows], column_names)`. You may find [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750921/5858851) helpful.

Comment: I figured the issue. The data returned from the source has all columns as strings. After changing the datatype in the source, it worked perfect. Thank you @user2722968