# PySpark Dataframe from Python Dictionary without Pandas

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert the following Python `dict` into PySpark DataFrame but I am not getting expected output.

```python
dict_lst = {'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
             'numbers': [10, 20, 30]}
df_dict = sc.parallelize([dict_lst]).toDF()  # Result not as expected
df_dict.show()
```

Is there a way to do this without using Pandas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750921/5858851):

> I find it's useful to think of the argument to createDataFrame() as a list of tuples where each entry in the list corresponds to a row in the DataFrame and each element of the tuple corresponds to a column.

So the easiest thing is to convert your dictionary into this format. You can easily do this using `zip()`:

```python
column_names, data = zip(*dict_lst.items())
spark.createDataFrame(zip(*data), column_names).show()
#+-------+-------+
#|letters|numbers|
#+-------+-------+
#|      a|     10|
#|      b|     20|
#|      c|     30|
#+-------+-------+
```

The above assumes that all of the lists are the same length. If this is not the case, you would have to use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (python2) or [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) (python3).

```python
from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest # use this for python2
#from itertools import zip_longest # use this for python3

dict_lst = {'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
             'numbers': [10, 20, 30, 40]}

column_names, data = zip(*dict_lst.items())

spark.createDataFrame(zip_longest(*data), column_names).show()
#+-------+-------+
#|letters|numbers|
#+-------+-------+
#|      a|     10|
#|      b|     20|
#|      c|     30|
#|   null|     40|
#+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `dict_lst` is not really the format you want to adopt to create a dataframe. It would be better if you had a list of dict instead of a dict of list.

This code creates a DataFrame from you dict of list :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

dict_lst = {'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
             'numbers': [10, 20, 30]}

values_lst = dict_lst.values()
nb_rows = [len(lst) for lst in values_lst]
assert min(nb_rows)==max(nb_rows) #We must have the same nb of elem for each key

row_lst = []
columns = dict_lst.keys()

for i in range(nb_rows[0]):
    row_values = [lst[i] for lst in values_lst]
    row_dict = {column: value for column, value in zip(columns, row_values)}
    row = Row(**row_dict)
    row_lst.append(row)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pault's` answer above I imposed a specific schema on my dataframe as follows:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('dictToDF').getOrCreate()
```

get data:

```
dict_lst = {'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c'],'numbers': [10, 20, 30]}
data = dict_lst.values()
```

create schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
myschema= StructType([ StructField("letters", StringType(), True)\
                      ,StructField("numbers", IntegerType(), True)\
                         ])
```

create df from dictionary - with schema:

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(zip(*data), schema = myschema)
df.show()
+-------+-------+
|letters|numbers|
+-------+-------+
|      a|     10|
|      b|     20|
|      c|     30|
+-------+-------+
```

show df schema:

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- letters: string (nullable = true)
 |-- numbers: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Python [List](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to quickly prototype a DataFrame. The idea is based from [Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html)'s tutorial.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a"), 
     (1, "a"), 
     (1, "b")],
    ("id", "value"))
df.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  1|    a|
|  1|    b|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out :

```
dict_lst = [{'letters': 'a', 'numbers': 10}, 
            {'letters': 'b', 'numbers': 20}, 
            {'letters': 'c', 'numbers': 30}]
df_dict = sc.parallelize(dict_lst).toDF()  # Result as expected
```

Output:

```
>>> df_dict.show()
+-------+-------+
|letters|numbers|
+-------+-------+
|      a|     10|
|      b|     20|
|      c|     30|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: This is not really scalable if his `dict_lst` doesn't come in this format.

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient approach is to use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(dict_lst))
```

Comment: It says 'without using Pandas' in the question.