# Pandas to PySpark: transforming a column of lists of tuples to separate columns for each tuple item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to transform a DataFrame in which one of the columns consists of a list of tuples, each item in each of the tuples has to be a separate column.

Here is an example and a solution in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {
    'a': {
        "1": "stuff", "2": "stuff2"
    }, 

    "d": {
        "1": [(1, 2), (3, 4)], "2": [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
print(df)  # intial structure

           a    d
    1   stuff   [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
    2   stuff2  [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

# first transformation, let's separate each list item into a new row
row_breakdown = df.set_index(["a"])["d"].apply(pd.Series).stack()
print(row_breakdown)

            a        
    stuff   0    (1, 2)
            1    (3, 4)
    stuff2  0    (1, 2)
            1    (3, 4)
    dtype: object

row_breakdown = row_breakdown.reset_index().drop(columns=["level_1"])
print(row_breakdown)

    a   0
    0   stuff   (1, 2)
    1   stuff   (3, 4)
    2   stuff2  (1, 2)
    3   stuff2  (3, 4)

# second transformation, let's get each tuple item into a separate column
row_breakdown.columns = ["a", "d"]
row_breakdown = row_breakdown["d"].apply(pd.Series)
row_breakdown.columns = ["value_1", "value_2"]
print(row_breakdown)

        value_1 value_2
    0   1   2
    1   3   4
    2   1   2
    3   3   4
```

This is the pandas solution. I need to be able to do the same but using PySpark (2.3). I have started working on it, but immediately got stuck:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("appName").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)

df_dict = {
    'a': {
        "1": "stuff", "2": "stuff2"
    }, 

    "d": {
        "1": [(1, 2), (3, 4)], "2": [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
ddf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

row_breakdown = ddf.set_index(["a"])["d"].apply(pd.Series).stack()

    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Apparently, Spark doesn't support indexing. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Spark DataFrames are unordered- so they don't have an index. What's the purpose of the key `a` here? All the information you need to construct the output is in `d`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I think it could be as simple as `row_breakdown = spark.createDataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df_dict["d"].values()), ["value1", "value2"])` (where `chain` is `from itertools import chain`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("appName").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)

df_dict = {
    'a': {
        "1": "stuff", "2": "stuff2"
    }, 

    "d": {
        "1": [(1, 2), (3, 4)], "2": [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
ddf = spark.createDataFrame(df)


exploded = ddf.withColumn('d', F.explode("d"))
exploded.show()
```

Result:

```
+------+------+
|     a|     d|
+------+------+
| stuff|[1, 2]|
| stuff|[3, 4]|
|stuff2|[1, 2]|
|stuff2|[3, 4]|
+------+------+
```

I feel more comfortable using SQL for this:

```
exploded.createOrReplaceTempView("exploded")
spark.sql("SELECT a, d._1 as value_1, d._2 as value_2 FROM exploded").show()
```

Important note: the reason why this is using the `_1` and `_2` accessors is because spark parsed the tuple as a structure and gave it default keys. If in your real implementation the dataframe contains an `array<int>`, you should use the `[0]` syntax.

The final result is:

```
+------+-------+-------+
|     a|value_1|value_2|
+------+-------+-------+
| stuff|      1|      2|
| stuff|      3|      4|
|stuff2|      1|      2|
|stuff2|      3|      4|
+------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

If you're starting from a DataFrame with the following schema:

```python
ddf.printSchema()
#root
# |-- a: string (nullable = true)
# |-- d: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = true)
```

You have to use `pyspark.sql.functions.explode` to explode the array into columns, but after that you can use the `*` selector to turn the struct into columns:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

row_breakdown = ddf.select("a", explode("d").alias("d")).select("a", "d.*")
row_breakdown.show()
#+------+---+---+
#|     a| _1| _2|
#+------+---+---+
#| stuff|  1|  2|
#| stuff|  3|  4|
#|stuff2|  1|  2|
#|stuff2|  3|  4|
#+------+---+---+
```

And to rename the columns, you can use a list comprehension with `str.replace`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

row_breakdown = row_breakdown.select(
    *[col(c).alias(c.replace("_", "value")) for c in row_breakdown.columns]
)
row_breakdown.show()
#+------+------+------+
#|     a|value1|value2|
#+------+------+------+
#| stuff|     1|     2|
#| stuff|     3|     4|
#|stuff2|     1|     2|
#|stuff2|     3|     4|
#+------+------+------+
```

---

**Original Answer**

If you're starting from the dictionary, you don't need to use `pandas` at all for this.

Instead, you can create your DataFrame directly from your dictionary. The key is to [transform your dictionary into the appropriate format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51561188/5858851), and then use that to build your Spark DataFrame.

In your example, it seems like you are not using the values under the `a` key at all.

As I [mentioned in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243200/pandas-to-pyspark-transforming-a-column-of-lists-of-tuples-to-separate-columns#comment91439756_52243200), you can achieve the described output with the following code:

```python
df_dict = {
    'a': {
        "1": "stuff", "2": "stuff2"
    }, 

    "d": {
        "1": [(1, 2), (3, 4)], "2": [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
    }
}

from itertools import chain
row_breakdown = spark.createDataFrame(
    chain.from_iterable(df_dict["d"].values()), ["value1", "value2"]
)
row_breakdown.show()
#+------+------+
#|value1|value2|
#+------+------+
#|     1|     2|
#|     3|     4|
#|     1|     2|
#|     3|     4|
#+------+------+
```

If  you want an index-like column, you can achieve that by simply using `enumerate`, as in the following example. Here I am also sorting the values by the key, as that seems to be your intention.

```python
data = (
    (i,) + v for i, v in enumerate(
        chain.from_iterable(
            v for k, v in sorted(df_dict["d"].items(), key=lambda (key, val): key)
        )
    )
)
columns = ["index", "value1", "value2"]
row_breakdown = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
row_breakdown.show()
#+-----+------+------+
#|index|value1|value2|
#+-----+------+------+
#|    0|     1|     2|
#|    1|     3|     4|
#|    2|     1|     2|
#|    3|     3|     4|
#+-----+------+------+
```

As you can see here, we can pass a generator expression to `spark.createDataFrame`, and this solution does not require us to know the length of the tuples ahead of time.

Comment: I don't start with a dictionary. I already use a DataFrame as per `ddf = spark.createDataFrame(df)`, the dictionary is just there for example. Using `chain.from_iterable(ddf["d"].values()), ["value1", "value2"]` gives me an error in PySpark: `the column is not callable`.