# How to create a PySpark DataFrame from a Python loop

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am looping through multiple webservices which works fine

```
customers= json.loads(GetCustomers())

for o in customers["result"]:
  if o["customerId"] is not None:
    custRoles = GetCustomersRoles(o["customerId"])
    custRolesObj = json.loads(custRoles)

    if custRolesObj["result"] is not None:
      for l in custRolesObj["result"]:
        print str(l["custId"]) + ", " + str(o["salesAmount"])
```

This works, and my output from print is also correct. But, now I need to create  a DataFrame out of this. I read, we cannot "create a DataFrame with two columns and add row by row while looping".

But how would I solve this?

**Update**

I hope this is the correct way to create a list?

```
customers= json.loads(GetCustomers())
result = []

for o in customers["result"]:
  if o["customerId"] is not None:
    custRoles = GetCustomersRoles(o["customerId"])
    custRolesObj = json.loads(custRoles)

    if custRolesObj["result"] is not None:
      for l in custRolesObj["result"]:
          result.append(make_opportunity(str(l["customerId"]), str(o["salesAmount"])))
```

When this is correct, how to create a Dataframe out of it?

Comment: Store your results in a list of tuples (or lists) and then create the spark DataFrame at the end. You *can* add a row inside a loop but it would be terribly inefficient

Comment: As @pault stated, I would definitely not add (or append) rows to a dataframe inside of a for loop. It will be terribly inefficient. Much more performant to create the dataframe all at once outside of the loop after assembling your data. On that note, you should include a sample of your data in your OP.

Comment: @pault: Could you give me a sample for a two column scenario please?

Comment: `df = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)], ["letter", "number"])`. Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750921/5858851).

Comment: @pault: thats not the solution. The problem is: how to do this from out of the for each loop.

Comment: Inside your loop append your columns to a list. Then create the dataframe outside of  your loop.

Comment: Thats what i know now and know how to imlement in theory. But how to do this practically eith a small code snippet. This would be the answer and what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the following code

```
customers= json.loads(GetCustomers())
result = []

for o in customers["result"]:
  if o["customerId"] is not None:
    custRoles = GetCustomersRoles(o["customerId"])
    custRolesObj = json.loads(custRoles)

    if custRolesObj["result"] is not None:
      for l in custRolesObj["result"]:
          result.append([str(l["customerId"]), str(o["salesAmount"])])

from pyspark.sql import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(result,['customerId', 'salesAmount'])
```